# iOS Bluetooth events in the background

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, background, microsoft-band

I'm creating an iOS app that should receive events from a [Microsoft Health Band 2](https://developer.microsoftband.com/bandsdk), specifically my app is notified when the user taps a button on the band. Everything is paired, communicating, and working great in the foreground.

I run my iOS app, then hit the home button to put it in the background. If I go press the button on the band, my app logs the event to the debug console and sends the event to a server.

However, if I wait a few minutes, then go press the button again with my phone locked, nothing happens. If I foreground the app on my iOS device, all the missing events process at once.

**Is it theoretically possible to have a Bluetooth LE accessory wake my app up  in response to an irregular event?** What would I need to do to get this to work using Core Bluetooth?

It's possible that Microsoft implemented their SDK incorrectly. Is there anything I can do to know whether the problem is on their end or mine?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you have not set the [Bluetooth Central Background Execution Mode](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothBackgroundProcessingForIOSApps/PerformingTasksWhileYourAppIsInTheBackground.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013257-CH7-SW6). If you specify this key in your `Info.plist` then your app will wake up whenever you receive a callback on the `CBPeripheralDelegate` or `CBCentralManagerDelegate`. Both of these delegates are implemented somewhere deep down in the Microsoft SDK.